# Reverse one edge in networkx graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I found `DiGraph.reverse()` to reverse the direction of all edges in the directed graph, but is there a way to change the direction of a specific edge only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can certainly be done manually, but there's nothing in the API for it.

```
$ cat edges.py; echo; python edges.py 
import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2,{'weight':.5})
G.add_edge(3,4,{'weight':1.0})
attrs = G[1][2]
G.remove_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,1,attrs)
print G.edges(data=True)

[(2, 1, {'weight': 0.5}), (3, 4, {'weight': 1.0})]
$
```

Comment: Ok. You're deleting the edge and inserting a reverted edge. I wonder if there's an API function for this sort of graph modification.

Comment: I don't see one. Presumably in a directed graph, this isn't considered a modification of an edge since there could alredy be an edge in the other direction. I'm not sure if the API includes (or even should include) higher-level functionality like this, though the existence of the reverse function is certainly a tease.

Comment: Indeed... The existence of `reverse` could imply this also exists for individual edges.

Comment: The implementation of reverse makes it look unlikely: the in-place reverse of a DiGraph swaps the predecessor and successor dictionaries.