# NetworkX: How to reverse a directed edge in a MultiDiGraph?

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph

***Question***: How do I reverse an edge (i.e., reverse the nodes of an edge) in Networkx MultiDiGraph?

***Context***: I have a graph representing a water distribution network and am trying to find flow loops (water leaving a point and reaching the same point, such as in a pump pumping in circles). For this I have a directed MultiDiGraph representation of the network (u, v, name) and a list of flows by edge names, and am trying to make sure the directions of the edges correspond to those of the flows by flipping edges corresponding to pipes with negative flows.

I could not however find a straightforward way to reverse the nodes of an edge based on their attributes (namely, the flow through the edge). Any ideas on how to do that or of a smarter way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209310/reverse-one-edge-in-networkx-graph) post which suggests deleting and re-adding the edge with the same attributed but reversed nodes but I couldn't make it work with a MultiDiGraph. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NetworkX API does not include a function to reverse individual edges. The approach of deleting a directed edge and then adding the reverse edge will work with a `MultiDiGraph` as shown below.

### Reverse a Directed Edge in a MultiDiGraph

```py
from copy import deepcopy
import networkx as nx


def reverse_edge(graph, node1, node2):
    for key, data in graph.get_edge_data(node1, node2).items():
        graph.add_edge(node2, node1, key=key, **(deepcopy(data)))
    graph.remove_edge(node1, node2)


G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=0.5, color='blue')
G.add_edge(3, 4, weight=1.0, color='red')
reverse_edge(G, 1, 2)

print(G.edges(data=True))
```

### Output

```
[(2, 1, {'weight': 0.5, 'color': 'blue'}), (3, 4, {'weight': 1.0, 'color': 'red'})]
```